# HotJar suspicious UserAgent error, nothing on google, Trying to run a python scraper tool for sports odds tracking

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping, user-agent, hotjar

c:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\cloudbet(2).py:47: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,  executable_path=r"C:\Python\Python38\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54368/devtools/browser/77f2d50d-65c6-49bf-af5b-7923f3d40bfc
[0619/100243.424:INFO:CONSOLE(109)] "Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/84.0.4147.56 Safari/537.36", source: https://www.cloudbet.com/static/js/2.08e072ab.chunk.js (109)

Comment: Hi, did you find anything about this?

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue "with some websites". It was related to running Google Chrome webdriver in `headless` mode and that is showing in your post details.

> "Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) **HeadlessChrome**/84.0.4147.56 Safari/537.36"

The following options could help in resolving the issue:

- Running Chrome driver in normal mode instead of headless. Namely, remove `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` option.
- Running Chrome driver in headless mode, but bypass the auto generated user-agent with a normal-mode user agent by adding the following argument (as an example of that scenario) :

```
    userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.56 Safari/537.36"
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
```

- Try using headless Firefox instead.

Comment: Second option worked great for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is a Cloudbet Odds API available under https://docs.cloudbet.com/ that should make it easier to access odds.

Is there anything missing that you're looking for?