# Can't run Selenium script headless

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I created a script to automate a task I need to do every monday. To do so I start a driver with the following piece of code:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

From the snippets of code I found this should run my script in the background. However I get the following message:

```plaintext
[0117/134345.023:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Elevio warning. 
 Elevio is disabled. Either via JavaScript API, or from page settings. undefined", source: https://cdn.elev.io/sdk/main/v4/1641517832207/elevio-main.js (2)
[0117/134345.994:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Elevio warning. 
 Elevio is disabled. Either via JavaScript API, or from page settings. undefined", source: https://cdn.elev.io/sdk/main/v4/1641517832207/elevio-main.js (2)
[0117/134348.880:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36", source: https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-2048401.js?sv=6 (3)
[0117/134349.260:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36", source: https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-2048401.js?sv=6 (3)
```

Does anyone have a clue on what the problem could be and how to solve it? Everything works when I don't run the script in the background.

Running:

- Python 3.9.4
- Selenium 4.1.0
- webdriver-manager 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a known problem related to the user agent being sent in headless mode, take a look at the following post

[HotJar suspicious UserAgent error, nothing on google, Trying to run a python scraper tool for sports odds tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475252/hotjar-suspicious-useragent-error-nothing-on-google-trying-to-run-a-python-scr)